# Matlab transition matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, transition

I tried to find a function of matlab, I found 'tf' but I didn't know how to use it :/

So I am trying to write a code of transition matrix, from:

```
mat1=[1,1,1;
      1,1,0;
      1,0,0];
```

to this one:

```
mat2=[1,2,3;
      0,1,1;
      0,0,1]
```

I think I have to do something like:

```
a{1} * mat2(1,:) + a{2} * mat2(1,:) + a{3} * mat2(1,:) = mat1(1,:);
a{4} * mat2(2,:) + a{5} * mat2(2,:) + a{6} * mat2(2,:) = mat1(2,:);
a{7} * mat2(3,:) + a{8} * mat2(3,:) + a{9} * mat2(3,:) = mat1(3,:);
```

find the a{1}, a{2}, .... a{9} that solve these equations, and put it in the columns:

```
result = [a{1} a{4} a{7};
          a{2} a{5} a{8};
          a{3} a{6} a{9}];
```

Is my way good? can someone tell me please how to use the matlab function for creating a transition matrix for my matrices?

This is an example:

```
1(1,2,3)-1(0,1,1)-1(0,0,1) = (1,1,1)
1(1,2,3)-1(0,1,1)-2(0,0,1) = (1,1,0)
1(1,2,3)-2(0,1,1)-1(0,0,1) = (1,0,0)
```

then, the result should be:

```
result =    [1  1  1
            -1 -1 -2
            -1 -2 -1]
```

now if I take the vector (3, -1, -1) in the basis of B, I got (1,0,0) in the basis of c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [tf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/control/ref/tf.html) function computes the transfer function model. That does not seem to be in any way related to your problem.

**EDITED:**

Now I got it, so the result matrix `R` that you want is actually

```
R = (M1 * M2^-1)^T
```

hence

```
result = (mat1 * inv(mat2))';
```

where the transposition is simply due to your choice of picking the indices column-first.

However, I must underline that this solution yields

```
mat1 = result' * mat2;
```

so `R^T` is not the transition matrix from `M1` to `M2`, but the transition matrix from `M2` to `M1`.

Comment: @Alon: uhm, why should I transpose the result?

Answer (score 0):

TF() is transfer function. As in controls. For example, if the function is F(s) = (1/5s^2+2s+1) Numerator = [1] Denominator = [5 2 1] and therefore your transfer function F = tf([1], [5 2 2]). From here you can do a lot of fun engineering stuff like bode(F) and so on.

What I think you are trying to do is: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/132415